# LMDE: Install latest Iceweasel or Firefox

Tags: debian, linux-mint, iceweasel

I am using LMDE (Linux Mint Debian Edition).
By default, this ships with a quite old Firefox version (21.0). And if you install Iceweasel, it does not get better.

There are a number of forum posts about installing a newer version of Iceweasel OR Firefox. Ultimately a lot of them lead here: http://mozilla.debian.net/, where I am asked to add this repository to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian experimental main
```

and to install as follows

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -t experimental iceweasel
```

Unfortunately, this gets me into the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 iceweasel : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but 2.13-37 is to be installed
             Depends: xulrunner-23.0 (>= 23.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If this is relevant, here is my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian main upstream import
deb http://mirror.rts-informatique.fr/linuxmint/debian/latest testing main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.rts-informatique.fr/linuxmint/debian/latest/security testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.rts-informatique.fr/linuxmint/debian/latest/multimedia testing main non-free

deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free

# Opera sources added by smxi
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera sid non-free

# for Iceweasel 4
deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian experimental main
```

and my /etc/apt/sources.bk (which is probably just a backup file, is it?)

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian main upstream import
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest testing main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/security testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/multimedia testing main non-free
```

Comment: I should add, I prefer to install stuff with apt-get as opposed to directly downloading it.

Comment: Have your tried a `dist-upgrade`? Be very careful with the `libc` package(s) it's a core dependency.

Comment: going to try that, thank you - we'll see :)  
I'm going to remove the "experimental" line from sources.list before dist-upgrade, who knows what effect it could have..

Comment: dist-upgrade does nothing. not really surprising, considering that lmde is a "running release".

Answer (score 2):

Lucky you, I decided to create a **LMDE** *Virtual Machine* just to answer this question.

Like you, I tried a few things (`add-apt-repository`)

- the **firefox-next PPA** on Launchpad [*ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next*] (no change)
- enabling the Mint **unstable "romeo" repo** (no change)
- installing the packages from **debian experimental repo** [*deb mozilla.debian.net/ experimental iceweasel*] (no change)
- running `dist-upgrade` from **debian unstable repo** [*deb ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main*] (successfully worked with `iceweasel` 23 until rebooting borked the install)

Thought about just *compiling* `firefox` from *source*.

Unfortunately, the only other option that I'm aware of (besides waiting) is to repackage the `.deb` package from  the *firefox-next* PPA and [change the dependencies listed](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=35136). You would have to do that for each version though (and hope the only difference is the `~ubuntu` appended to the version number rather than compiled against a different version)

If a real *rolling release* is important to you and you're comfortable with **CLI** then I'd highly recommend taking the leap to [ArchLinux](https://www.archlinux.org/) or [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/).

Comment: sorry, my reputation does not allow to vote you up :( but thanks for the effort!

Comment: Are ArchLinux and Gentoo generally better maintained than LMDE?